# How can I upload file from Rest API in Codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

I am new to codeigniter 3. I am accepting parameter as follows for saving a file from android app. I am receiving only the file path like this. However the exact file is not getting stored in the folder

```
file:///storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.xyz/files/compressed/IMG_1599745033164.png



    public function updateUsername(){
                header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
                header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, OPTIONS');
                header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization, X-Request-With');
                header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true');
$nameval = $this->security->xss_clean($this->input->post('nameval'));
    $image = base64_decode($nameval);
                    
    
        $image_name = md5(uniqid(rand(), true));
                        $filename = $image_name . '.' . 'jpg';
                        //rename file name with random number
        
                        $path = "uploads/categoryimages/".$filename;
                        //image uploading folder path
                        file_put_contents($path . $filename, $image);
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

I can share my code here which I have done for the same problem and its working.
JSON post Data format

Step 1: Convert image into base64 like

data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD/4Q2CRXhpZgAASUkqAAgAAAAOAAsAAgAKAAAAtgmv/9k=

Step 2: Encode above base64 data by using base64 encoding. You will get code like

ZGF0YTppbWFnZS9qcGVnO2Jhc2U2NCwvOWovNEFBUVNrWkpSZ0FCQVFBQUFRQUJBQUQvNFEyQ1JYaHBaZ0FBU1VrcUFBZ0FBQUFPQUFzQUFnQUtBQUFBdGdtdi85az0=
Then use this encoded base64 into JSON object value

Post Data API: http://url/controller/function

{
"media_type": "png",
"imagecode": "ZGF0YTppbWFnZS9qcGVnO2Jhc2U2NCwvOWovNEFBUVNrWkpSZ0FCQVFBQUFRQUJBQUQvNFEyQ1JYaHBaZ0FBU1VrcUFBZ0FBQUFPQUFzQUFnQUtBQUFBdGdtdi85az0="
}

--------------------------------Codeigniter controller -------------
I am sharing exact function which is receving image data and saving into local directory.

```
function upload_profile_photo(){
            $this->load->model('api_logs_model');

            $emp_user_id = $this->input->post('user_id');//$_POST['user_id'];
        
            $img_details = $this->api_logs_model->get_user_image_data($emp_user_id);

            //var_dump($emp_user_id);exit;
            $path = '/var/www/html/empengapp/uploads/images/'.$emp_user_id;
            
            $image_path='uploads/images/'.$emp_user_id;
      
            $new_name = date('ymd') . time();
                     
             if (!file_exists($path)) {
                    mkdir($path, 0755, true);
                 }

                $config['upload_path']          = $path;
                $config['allowed_types']        = 'jpg|jpeg|png';
                $config['max_size']             = 5000;
                $config['max_width']            = 1800;
                $config['max_height']           = 1800;
                $config['file_name']            = $new_name;
               
                

                $this->load->library('upload', $config);

                             
               
                if(!$this->upload->do_upload('user_image'))
                {
                        
                        
                        $resp['msg']    = $this->upload->display_errors();
                        $resp['status'] = false;
                        

                       // $this->load->view('slider-images-view', $error);
                }
                else
                {
                                                 
                        $image_details = $this->upload->data();

                        $img_data = array(
                            'user_id'           =>  $emp_user_id,
                            'path'              =>  $image_path,
                            'file_name'         =>  $image_details['file_name'],
                            'upload_time'       =>  date('Y-m-d h:m:s')
                        );

                    //var_dump($img_data);exit;
                    if ($img_details) { 
                        $path = $img_details['path'];
                        $file_name = $img_details['file_name'];

                        $file_status = $path.'/'.$file_name; 
                                if (file_exists($file_status))
                                {
                                    $del_status = unlink($file_status);
                                    //var_dump($del_status);exit;
                                    if ($del_status) {
                                        $this->api_logs_model->delete_user_profile_pic($img_details['image_id']);
                                        $result = $this->api_logs_model->update_image_details_data($img_data, $img_details); 
                                        if ($result){ 
                                            $resp['status'] = true;
                                            $resp['msg'] = 'Profile uploaded successfully';
                                        }else{
                                            $resp['status'] = false;
                                            $resp['msg'] = 'Photo uploaded but information not saved.';
                                        }
                                    }else{
                                        $resp['status'] = false;
                                        $resp['msg'] = 'failed to remove existing profile picture!';
                                    }                       
                                }//end of if
                        
                    }else{
                        $result = $this->api_logs_model->submit_image_details($img_data); 
                        if ($result){ 
                            $resp['status'] = true;
                            $resp['msg'] = 'Profile uploaded successfully';
                        }else{
                            $resp['status'] = false;
                            $resp['msg'] = 'Photo uploaded but information not saved.';
                        }   
                    }
                                
                    
                }

                $this->output
                ->set_status_header(200)
                ->set_content_type('application/json', 'utf-8')
                ->set_output(json_encode($resp, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT | JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE | JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES))
                ->_display();
                exit;
    }//end of function upload_profile_photo
```

You can ping me for any related question. I will help you out. Thanks